# nth order fourier series curve fitting in Python

Tags: python, fft, curve-fitting

I've been looking for a way to code a snippet in Python which calculate for any n-th order of Fourier series curve fitting. To calculate a certain order of Fourier series curve fitting, say 3 order is quite simple, however to do it where the order n is variable, still not workable yet. Perhaps somebody has done it, but my searching can't find it yet. I wonder if anybody could give a help. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want to calculate the Fourier coefficients of an arbitrary function? (well, _periodical_ arbitrary function)

Comment: Hai Evpok. Yes, that's correct.

Comment: For example I have a known periodic data, x, or a arbitrary periodic function, and want to calculate the coefficients. I'd image a function, cosCoeffs, sinCoeffs = fourier(x, T, N), where T is the period and N is arbitrary order. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Well the formula is

```
n-th cos_coeff = (2/T)*integral(-T/2,T/2, f(t)*cos(n*t*2*pi/2)dt)
n-th sin coeff = (2/T)*integral(-T/2,T/2, f(t)*sin(n*t*2*pi/2)dt)
```

Check [scypi](http://scipy.org/) and [scipy.integrate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) for details on integration.

Here it should be

```
cos_coeff(f, T, N) = (2/T)*quad(lambda t: f(t)*cos(N*t*2*math.pi/2),-T/2,T/2)
```

(Not tested, though)

I am not familiar with Discrete Fourier Transform, but you can perhaps compute said coefficient from it, too. Check
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fftpack.html